# How to programmatically record video without showing camera view in an iPad app?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I want to record video in an app without showing camera view to the user so that we can come to know who has used the app.

Please can you advise?
Thanks

Comment: I hope this isn't possible. Scary.

Comment: Can you please provide some proof of this? Such as apple doc.

Comment: I didn't say that it isn't possible (I don't know if it is or not). I was stating an opinion that it would be scary if it is possible. Being able to make secret video recordings is a bad idea (in my opinion).

Comment: Ok thanks. Can we customize camera view and auto record video and show camera view in a very small area in the app? Please advice

Comment: You can add recording code in any event u want, also u can set camera view frame 2X2 pixls also but can't say recorded video size. another thing u can do is take two view topview and bottom view. do whatever u want on topview and on bottom view u add cameraview layer. so user wud c top view only but we will be getting camera feed from bottom view layer. just a trick if it works.  heres a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897950/video-recording-using-avfoundation