# How can i record video without opening video camera?

Tags: iphone, ios, video

How can i record video without opening any camera? My requirement is when a person is in problem his video is recorded but not by opening camera it should work in background.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [AVFoundation Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html) for `video capturing`.

Don't add `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to see whats been `recorded` in current `UIView`

Comment: can you provide some sample demo if you have?